# Why is the word "animal" not an adjective here?

Tags: adjectives

We know that when something tells the property of a noun, we call it *an adjective*. For example

- Tommy is **beautiful**

So, **beautiful** is *an adjective* because it is telling the property of Tommy.

Now take another example:

- Tommy is an **animal**

**Animal** is also telling the property of the noun but why isn't **animal** *an adjective* in the second sentence?

Comment: Because it is a noun here. There's an article before it and no object to which it could refer should it be an adjective. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/animal

Comment: @SovereignSun Thanks, I get it. If we say "They are observing animal life" Where life is an object after animal. So in this case animal is an adjective. In all other cases animal is a noun

Comment: "He is animal" is also possible, means "He acts as if he were an animal"

Comment: It is possible to use nouns like adjectives in English, as in *race horse* or *car door*, which might be confusing for you.  This is called a *noun adjunct*.

Comment: More specifically, you can call it a predicative complement.

Comment: @beginner you have the right idea, but in your example "They are observing animal life," "animal" is not an adjective *per se*.  It is, as stangdon said, a "noun adjunct," which means a noun that modifies another noun.  It's worth being aware that it is still a noun, not an adjective, even though it functions like one.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct

Answer (score 2):

*Animal* is not an adjective because it has an article before it.  Nouns take articles, never adjectives.

If you say "Tommy is animalish" or "Tommy is animalistic" - those are adjectives.

I think this is a "predicate nominative" situation where you are renaming the subject, not a "subject complement" where you are describing properties directly.

In saying "Tommy is an animal" - we are using figurative tactics here, we don't mean he is literally an animal even though we are literally saying that.  The "Tommy has the properties of an animal" is implied.